# Is multiple inheritance from the same base class via different parent classes really an issue here?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to implement an inheritance hierarchy in my C++ game engine that has some analogies from Java:

- all objects inherit from `Object` class,
- some functionality is provided by interfaces.

It's **just an analogy** that gives me some benefits (**not a strict 1:1 Java:C++ mapping** which is not possible).

**By "interface" I mean here a class with only pure virtual, public methods.** I know that it's not a strict and precise definition of it.

So I've made:

```
class Object{...};

/* interfaces */
class Nameable : public Object{...};
class Moveable : public Object{...};
class Moveable3D : public Moveable{...};
class Moveable2D : public Moveable{...};

class Model3D : public Moveable3D, public Nameable{...}
class Line3D : public Moveable3D{...}
class Level: public Nameable{...}
class PathSolver : public Object{...}
```

As you can see, `Model3D` now inherits from `Object` via multiple ways:

- `Moveable3D -> Moveable -> Object`,
- `Nameable -> Object`.

And my compiler in VS2013 (VC++) **warns me about it**.

**Is that an issue?**

**If so, how to solve it to get a better inheritance structure?**

I was thinking about two ways, but both have more disadvantages then advantages:

1. Dropping the inheritance between e.g. `Nameable` and `Object`. But that way `Level` would lost its inheritance from `Object` too (and my first goal was: *all objects inherit from `Object` class*).
2. I could also drop `: public Object` **from each interface**. But that way I would be force to manually type `:public Object` in each of many engine final classes (`Model3D`, `Line3D`, `Level`, `PathSolver`). **That way both refactoring and creating new final types would be harder.** Moreover the information that each interface will be guaranteed to inherit from `Object` is lost that way.

I would like to avoid virtual inheritance (one level of abstraction further) **if** it's not necessary. But maybe it is (at least for `: public Object`)?

Comment: @jxh I'm not sure what are you asking for. But: any `Nameable` is guaranteed to be `Object` (same for `Moveable3D`). But `Moveable3D` don't have to be `Nameable` at the same time. When you pass `Object *` you cannot assume it's `Nameable` or `Moveable3D`, but you can e.g. use `dynamic_cast` to check it. And of course you can assign any other type to `Object *` (that would be best). **Moreover** all interfaces have pure virtual method so you cannot use them with just `new Nameable()`, you have to inherit from them first. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Your current structure means that `Model3D` has two `Object` instances. So, if you try to assign it to an `Object` reference, then you will get an ambiguity error unless you specify which `Object` to refer to (the one towards `Nameable` or the one towards `Moveable3D`). But, if you use virtual inheritance, you will only have one `Object` (`Nameable` and `Moveable3D` share the same `Object` instance).

Comment: Is `Object` an interface?

Comment: @jxh it **can** be if that helps - I've only assigned methods like `virtual string getDebugInfo() = 0;` to it so far and I may make an guarantee to keep it as interface.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[As said by Juraj Blaho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27546677/839601) the canonical way to solve this problem is virtual inheritance. One implementation model for virtual inheritance is to add an entry in the vtable of classes using virtual inheritance pointing to the real unique object from the base class. That way, you get the following inheritance graph :

```
             Model3D
            /       \
     Moveable3D   Nameable
           |         |
      Moveable       |
            \       /
             Object
```

That is you must have :

```
class Nameable : public virtual Object{...};
class Moveable : public virtual Object{...};
```

The other classes do not need virtual inheritance

---

Without virtual inheritance the graph would have been

```
             Model3D
            /       \
     Moveable3D   Nameable
           |         |
      Moveable       |
           |         |
        Object    Object
```

with 2 distinct instances of Object

The most tricky part in virtual inheritance is the call of constructors (ref [Virtual Inheritance in C++, and solving the diamond problem](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html)) *Because there is only a single instance of a virtual base class that is shared by multiple classes that inherit from it, the constructor for a virtual base class is not called by the class that inherits from it (which is how constructors are called, when each class has its own copy of its parent class) since that would mean the constructor would run multiple times. Instead, the constructor is called by the constructor of the concrete class.* ... *By the way, the constructors for virtual base classes are always called before the constructors for non-virtual base classes. This ensures that a class inheriting from a virtual base class can be sure the virtual base class is safe to use inside the inheriting class's constructor. The destructor order in a class hierarchy with a virtual base class follows the same rules as the rest of C++: the destructors run in the opposite order of the constructors. In other words, the virtual base class will be the last object destroyed, because it is the first object that is fully constructed.*

But the real problem is that this *Dreadful Diamond on Derivation* is often considered as a bad hierarchy design and is explicitely forbidden in Java.

But IMHO, what C++ virtual inheritance does under the hood is not that far from what you would have if all your interface classes were pure abstract classes (only pure virtual public methods) not inheriting from Object and if all you implementation classes did inherit explicitely from Object. Using it or not is up to you : after all it is part of the language ...

Comment: Great one. So far I like your respond the most :) Illustration of the problem, solution and "be aware of ... [when you use that solution]" part makes it a complete answer. Thank you, sir.

Comment: "is explicitely forbidden in Java" Well, Java doesn’t feature multiple inheritance at all...

Comment: Another way of avoiding such issues is by requiring that any virtual methods defined in types above the 'split' only be overridden by types below the 'join'.  This is the approach taken by .NET, and that used to be taken by Java.

Answer (score 5):

Use virtual inheritance of interfaces. That will ensure that there is only one instance of base class in the derived classes:

```
class Object{...};

/* interfaces */
class Nameable : public virtual Object{...};
class Moveable : public virtual Object{...};
class Moveable3D : public virtual Moveable{...};
class Moveable2D : public virtual Moveable{...};

class Model3D : public virtual Moveable3D, public virtual Nameable{...}
class Line3D : public virtual Moveable3D{...}
class Level: public virtual Nameable{...}
class PathSolver : public virtual Object{...}
```

Without virtual inheritance there are multiple instances of the same base in the object which will cause that you will not be able to substitute the concrete type where the interface is needed:

```
void workWithObject(Object &o);

Model3D model;
workWithObject(model);
```

Comment: Maybe that's the solution here. However I guess I can reduce the usage of virtual inheritance to inheritance from `Object`. **What disadvantages would the usage of virtual inheritance bring to me in exchange** for solving the problem?

Comment: @PolGraphic: Yes, you can limit that to inheritance from `Object`. A state of the art approach for C++ game engine is not to use inheritance, but use composition (component/entity system). But that sounds too off-topic for the question asked. Some information for example at: http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/

Comment: thanks :) And the link you provided is really worth a reading :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is an issue: In the memory layout of `Model3D`, there are two subobjects of type `Object`; one is a subobject of `Movable3D`, the other of `Nameable`. As such, these two subobjects may contain different data. This is especially a problem, if the object class contains functionality that has to do with the identity of an object. For instance, an `Object` class that implements reference counting must be a unique subobject of all objects; an object that has two different reference counts is very likely a very bad idea...

To avoid this, use virtual inheritance. The only virtual inheritance that is needed is from the `Object` base class:

```
class Objec{...];

class Nameable : public virtual Object{...};
class Moveable : public virtual Object{...};
class Moveable3D : public Moveable{...};
class Moveable2D : public Moveable{...};

class Model3D : public Movable3D, public Nameable{...};
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I see how virtual inheritance solves the issue here. But I'm also curious - are there any problems that virtual inheritance instead of "normal" one brings to my specific model in exchange? That would be great if you could deny it or shortly name any of them (if it's possible). Still, great respond with nice explanation :)

Comment: The only drawback is a few CPU cycles of additional latency when calling virtual functions / downcasting base class pointers: When you downcast without virtual inheritance, the pointer is adjusted by a constant amount of bytes; with virtual inheritance, a lookup from the vtable is required to find the correct offset. That's all.

Comment: Thank you. The call will take "longer" only for methods that are inherited virtually from the `Object` or for any virtual method declared in any class (e.g. method declared in `Moveable3D` when only `Moveable` inherit virtually from `Object`)?

Comment: I can't really answer that one. But I don't think it's relevant. The additional overhead is that of loading one value from memory, which is in cache anyway if the function call is performance critical. It's definitely less than the overhead of even calling a function.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual inheritance will bring order in your class hierarchy. A few things to watch for:

- Don't mix virtual/non-virtual inheritance for the same base class in your hierarchy unless you really know what you are doing.
- Initialization order becomes tricky. Constructor of the virtually inherited class will be called only once. The constructor will take arguments from the most derived class. If you don't specify it explicitly in Moveable3D the default constructor will be called, even if Moveable specified arguments for Object's constructor. So, to avoid the mess make sure you use only DEFAULT constructors in all classes you inherit virtually.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that `Model3D` ( which is using multiple inheritance ) has to provide interface from both its' base classes i.e `Nameable` as well as `Model3D`. Because from the name you have provided to your class it seems to me that `Nameable` should better be implemented as a member of `'Model3D'`.

Apart from that most of issues in multiple inheritance comes if base classes have their own data. Like then you have to decide whether base class would be virtual OR not and etc... However, you mentioned that base classes are all interface i.e with at least one pure virtual function. So, I think you can avoid many problems of multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ravi thank you for the suggestion to check the possibility of containing vs inheritance in my model. It's more complex then what I've posted in question (to make it readable), but it's a perfect point in many many places of my structure. However, I don't think its a cure in all of them. Up-voted for now - I won't accept it yet to give a chance for other ideas to be presented :)